# Initialize database without XML configuration, but using @Configuration

Tags: java, spring, h2

I would like to know how to initialize a database without having to create an XML file.

I already use this kind of initialization that works fine, but in my current case I don't want to create an XML:

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
  <jdbc:script location="classpath:com/foo/sql/db-schema.sql"/>
  <jdbc:script location="classpath:com/foo/sql/db-test-data.sql"/>
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

I know I can create an embedded database with:

```
EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
EmbeddedDatabase db = builder.setType(H2).addScript("my-schema.sql").addScript("my-test-data.sql").build();
```

In my case, the database and schema are created using Liquibase.

I just want to initialize it with Spring and with my customized dataset, without having to create a new XML file each time just for that.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After looking at Spring classes related to EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder I found out that the DatabaseBuilder is using some code looking like this:

```
ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
for (String sqlScript: sqlInitializationScripts ) {
  Resource sqlScriptResource = RESOURCE_LOADER.getResource(sqlScript);
  populator.addScript(sqlScriptResource);
}
DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(populator, dataSource);
```

This will work fine for me, even if it will be on a @BeforeTest method and not on the Spring configuration.

Comment: It works. Use new ClassPathResource(sqlScript) to get the resource.

Comment: Looks like you have changed your question. This answer does not look related to the question in my opinion. The first answer makes more sense.

Answer (score 35):

The following lines of code inside your `@Configuration` class might work.

```
@Value("classpath:com/foo/sql/db-schema.sql")
private Resource schemaScript;

@Value("classpath:com/foo/sql/db-test-data.sql")
private Resource dataScript;

@Bean
public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(final DataSource dataSource) {
    final DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    initializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    initializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator());
    return initializer;
}

private DatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
    final ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    populator.addScript(schemaScript);
    populator.addScript(dataScript);
    return populator;
}
```

Comment: That looks reasonable, but I think it'd need to be inside a bean to get the `@Value` annotations wired up? Is that much different from using the configuration attribute the OP was trying to avoid? (From his own answer, OP was trying to set up a unit test which this wouldn't help with either I think.)

Comment: yes this doesn't help much than my answer, at least for my usecase

Comment: In my case this initializer script will be executed on every startup... how can i limit that to the first start?

Answer (score 27):

You have to create your own `schema.sql` and put it in your `src/main/resources`-folder.

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulator;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator;

@Configuration
public class DataSourceInitializer {

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource(){
        DataSource dataSource = createDataSource();
        DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(createDatabasePopulator(), dataSource);
        return dataSource;
    }

    private DatabasePopulator createDatabasePopulator() {
        ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        databasePopulator.setContinueOnError(true);
        databasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("schema.sql"));
        return databasePopulator;
    }

    private SimpleDriverDataSource createDataSource() {
        SimpleDriverDataSource simpleDriverDataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        simpleDriverDataSource.setDriverClass(org.h2.Driver.class);
        simpleDriverDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:target/database/example;AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE");
        simpleDriverDataSource.setUsername("");
        simpleDriverDataSource.setPassword("");
        return simpleDriverDataSource;      
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but not sure it adds anything to the existing answers?

Comment: @SebastienLorber I had a few issues with the Value annotation, so i had to rewrite it. And above is my result and it works :)

Answer (score 6):

It certainly is possible.

If you already have an `@Configuration` class that is being loaded by Spring's `ApplicationContext`, then you simply have to create a new `@Bean` method that will contain the code you have there already (with an additional `return` statement of course).

`EmbeddedDatabase` implements the `DataSource` interface, so it can easily be used with `JdbcTemplate`'s.

```
@Bean
public DataSource db() {
    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
    builder.setType(H2).addScript("my-schema.sql").addScript("my-test-data.sql");
    return builder.build();
}
```

Comment: No that's not it, I don't want to create a new DataSource: I already have one!

Comment: Well, then you can change the return type to be `EmbeddedDatabase` if you want, as an `EmbeddedDatabase` is a `DataSource`.  All I am suggesting here is that you can use the `DataSource` easily with `JdbcTemplate`.