# Is it possible to add scripts dynamically with spring embedded database?

Tags: spring, h2, embedded-database

is it possible, to add scripts to the EmbeddedDatabase of Spring dynamically? I get for example 3 scripts per parameter, so i want to add these 3. The next time I only want to add 2 scripts.
It will only used in development mode, but developers can decided themselves, which scripts they want to use, cause they want to test different data as another.

I hope you understand my question :)

Greetings!

Comment: You should explain a bit more. Not sure about what you are trying to achieve. Can you maybe post some pseudo-code or pseudo-XML example of your *ideal configuration*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like:

```
private DatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
    final ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    populator.addScript(schemaScript);
    populator.addScript(dataScript);
    return populator;
```

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038360/initialize-database-without-xml-configuration-but-using-configuration)