# @Configuration class is not called

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

in my spring application, i am using h2, and i am trying to populate data inside the db.

Here is my class:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    String  username;
    String  password;
    String  role;
    boolean activated;
}
```

and then i saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038360/initialize-database-without-xml-configuration-but-using-configuration) question, and made the following class to populate data inside it

```
@Configuration

public class DataBaseInitializer {

@Value("classpath:schema.sql")
private Resource schemaScript;


@Value("classpath:data.sql")
private Resource dataScript;

@Bean
public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(final DataSource dataSource) {
    final DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    initializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    initializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator());
    return initializer;
}

    private DatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
        final ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        populator.addScript(schemaScript);
        populator.addScript(dataScript);
       System.out.println("data shoul be populated");
        return populator;
        }
}
```

and in the `src/main/resources`-folder `schema.sql` i have:

```
insert into user (id,activated,password,role,username)values(4,true,'12345','Admin','admin');
```

and the `schema.sql` file is:

```
create table 
    if not exists
        user (  id int not null primary key,
                username varchar(50) not null,
                password varchar(50) not null, 
                activated boolean not null,
                role varchar(50) not null);
```

and i have added `spring.datasource.initialize=true`
Unfortunately, when i run the application there is no record on user table

I set the debug like   `System.out.println("data shoul be populated");`, but it never get printed in my console

Comment: Are you using hibernate or jpa @Entity? If JPA then you can look at the specification and set the properties. "spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target=some-schema.sql" and 
"spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action=create" Hibernate has similar as does spring data.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Spring Data JPA reference manual regarding the database initialization: [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html), it states that there are two distinct files that, the framework consideres during initialization: `schema.sql` and `data.sql`.

If you want to override the auto-generation (or ommit it) of schema, then you fill in the `schema.sql`.

Once the schema is created, spring invokes the statements contained in the `data.sql`. This is where you want to put your insert statements. If you put them inside the `schema.sql` and do not put DDL statement before those inserts, then you will be inserting to tables that do not exist.

In your application.properties file you may also need this:

```
spring.datasource.initialize=true
```

Comment: i have updated my questin. right now, there is no record on the table